# Superflous 'Not Authorized' Error in CP

Tags: control-panel, error

When trying to add an entry from the CP with a user in an 'Editors' group (not SuperAdmin) I get this error on being redirected after submitting the entry:

[quote]An Error Was Encountered
You are not authorized to access this page[/quote]

The actual entry submits fine - so it is not really an error at all - it just goes to this error rather than the usual screen which shows on successful submission. I CAN fix it by enabling "Can view channel entries authored by others" in the group permissions but I don't want to do this because:

a) it shouldn't really affect it - this is nothing to do with any other user and more importantly:
b) I don't want this group to see the other entries - only their own entries.

This is in EE 2.7.3 - any suggestions? Surely this is not normal behaviour?

Comment: after you add the entry can you see it in editing entries page??

Comment: Yes, it is there - it posts the entry perfectly, just gives an error on the screen it is redirected to, the one that normally shows some details and gives and 'edit this entry' link.

I should say I am also using Zoo Visitor and this is the channel for the member entries - essentially it is registering a member, don't think this is significant though.

Comment: so after you add the entry you can see and access the entry from the same 'Editors' member? and please check if the author field assigned to the same 'Editors' member

Comment: Problem is I'm using Zoo Visitor and was hoping that Admins (not SuperAdmin) could add Members where ADMIN IS the author and NOT the new User. Seems this is not possible even if Admins register someone - user's Author field will still be their own name and not the Admins.

Comment: Because of this I can't actually check whether they can personally see it (I know Super Admins can) but it's a moot point because I need to have the User Author = Admin who registered them and this is not possible which in turn means I can't use the CP for this - am going to need another approach via Channel Form so I guess this is all a non-issue now.....thanks for your help though!

Comment: I'm seeing this in the latest version of EE as well.